# Parse.com Cloud Code - Set Priority on Apple Push Notification

Tags: ios, parse-platform, apple-push-notifications

I'm looking to add a priority of 10 to some push notifications I'm sending from Parse's Push Cloud Code -- does anyone have any ideas of how to do so? I can't seem to find any mention of priority in the Parse docs.

Reference to using priority with Apple Pushes: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/CommunicatingWIthAPS.html